# Save array of objects in odata API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2

Using following function I can create or edit single objects. Now I want to create edit or edit array of objects instead on one is each request.

```
 // POST odata/Project
        public IHttpActionResult Post(ProjectModel projectmodel)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.Projects.Add(projectmodel);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return Created(projectmodel);
        }
 // PUT odata/Project(5)
        public IHttpActionResult Put([FromODataUri] int key, ProjectModel projectmodel)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (key != projectmodel.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Entry(projectmodel).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ProjectModelExists(key))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return Updated(projectmodel);
        }
```

How do I create or edit for array of objects ?

Comment: accept IEnumerable<ProjetModel> for your actions.

Comment: Could you please explain !

Comment: You may also try with Batch request.http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataBatchSample/